# Overriding template with hooks

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am having a little trouble editing a Woocommerce template with hooks. Essentially I would just like to change the `product-image` template so instead of linking to the uploaded product image, it links to the product post.

The current `product-image.php` woocommerce template has

```
global $post, $woocommerce, $product;

?>
<div class="images">

<?php
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {

        $image_title        = esc_attr( get_the_title( get_post_thumbnail_id() ) );
        $image_link         = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() );
        $image              = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, apply_filters( 'single_product_large_thumbnail_size', 'shop_single' ), array(
            'title' => $image_title
            ) );
        $attachment_count   = count( $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids() );

        if ( $attachment_count > 0 ) {
            $gallery = '[product-gallery]';
        } else {
            $gallery = '';
        }

        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_html', sprintf( '<a href="%s" itemprop="image" class="woocommerce-main-image zoom" title="%s"  rel="prettyPhoto' . $gallery . '">%s</a>', $image_link, $image_title, $image ), $post->ID );

    } else {

        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_html', sprintf( '<img src="%s" alt="Placeholder" />', woocommerce_placeholder_img_src() ), $post->ID );

    }
?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails' ); ?>

</div>
```

I am unsure of how to adapt the `echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_html', sprintf( '<a href="%s" itemprop="image" class="woocommerce-main-image zoom" title="%s"  rel="prettyPhoto' . $gallery . '">%s</a>', $image_link, $image_title, $image ), $post->ID );` to change the `%s` to a link to the post.

The hook I am using is:

```
add_action('woocommerce_product_thumbnails', 'custom_links');

function custom_links() {
//code
}
```

Could someone help me gain some direction with this?

Answer (score 1):

You are calling action not filter. Also you are calling the wrong one.

Change this:

```
add_action('woocommerce_product_thumbnails', 'custom_links');
```

to this:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_single_product_image_html', 'custom_links', 10, 2);
```

The `2` represents the argument count for the function and your `custom_links()` should be something like:

```
function custom_links($link, $post_id) {
    $pattern = '/(?<=href=")([^"]*)/';
    $replacement = get_permalink($post->ID);
    return preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $link);
}
```

Process the `$link` variable as needed and then return it.

Comment: Thanks for the response! The function appears to be working, however when I change the value of `$link` it removes the picture, any idea how I could just change the href and leave the src the same?

Comment: @Chris That's because $link variable contains html like "<a><img></a>". Either use preg_replace() (or any other string functions) to modify only url or just regenerate whole string. You have product ID. Just get image and url and redo the string.

Comment: I am getting fatal errors when I try to replace the $link string. I.E. to get it to just show the image, without even trying to link it to the post `function custom_links($link, $post_id) {
    $link = "<img src="$image">";
 
  return $link;
}` I think I am missing a rule here.

Comment: @Chris that's because your double quotes are wrong and you don't have $image variable. You can't access same variables that were in template. `function custom_links($link, $post_id) {
  $pattern = '/(?<=href=")([^"]*)/';
  $replacement = get_permalink($post->ID);
  return preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $link));
 })`